# How to replace numbers given a condition without the output 'true' or 'false' back

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need to replace numbers in a dataframe column with a condition where no numbers less than 300 or greater than 900 exist. When I try to add a condition like that, I get true or false outputs and I need it done in numbers. This is what I have:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(data=distances)
df

parallax
0   567.170891
1   677.524304
2   422.738804
3   638.037667
4   9927.293477
... ...
288 1142.040121
289 218.383978
290 506.344691
291 NaN
292 NaN
```

then

```
new_df=df.loc[df['parallax'] >= 300, 'parallax'] <= 900
new_df

0       True
1       True
2       True
3       True
4      False
       ...  
284    False
285    False
287    False
288    False
290     True
```

Why does it return like that and how can I take out the False and have the numbers back? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `df.loc[df['parallax'] >= 300, 'parallax'] <= 900` does not make sense. Did you mean `df[df['parallax'] >= 300 & df['parallax'] <= 900]`?

Comment: @Amadan When I try that, i get the error "TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot parentheses. `&` binds more powerfully than `<=`. Try `df[(df['parallax'] >= 300) & (df['parallax'] <= 900)]`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the comment off the top of my head, forgot about priority. The correct answer is

```
new_df = df[(df['parallax'] >= 300) & (df['parallax'] <= 900)]
```

`df['parallax'] >= 360` makes a Boolean `Series`, as does `df['parallax'] <= 900`. We use `&` operator to produce a new Boolean `Series` that matches both conditions. Then we select only the rows where this selector `Series` is `True`.

I don't know what you mean by "replace", since there was no replacing in your code. If that was merely a typo for "select", then that is your answer. If you wanted to replace the numbers that are outside the range with something else, like `NaN`, then use a different approach: select the rows that do *not* match the criteria.

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df[(df['parallax'] < 300) | (df['parallax'] > 900)] = np.nan
```

And if you want to replace the values outside the range with the boundary, use `clip` method:

```
new_df = df.copy()
new_df['parallax'].clip(300, 900, inplace=True)
```

(Of course, if you don't need the old data frame, you don't need to make a copy.)

Answer (score -1):

To accomplish what you want you can use the pandas `.apply()` function, which applies a function to each element of a DataSeries.

For example:

```py
def cap_values(value):
    if (value > 300 and value < 900):
        return value
    else:
        return 300 if value < 300 else 900
df= pd.DataFrame(data=distances)
df['parallax']= df['parallax'].apply(cap_values)
```

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't: `apply` uses a Python callback on each row, which destroys any advantage of using `numpy` / `pandas`. `apply` should be reserved only for cases where you absolutely can't vectorise the operation in any other way, as means of last resort.